# python socket server with arguments

Tags: python, sockets

Hello so I am making a python socket server and client and I am trying to figure out how I can make it so when the server sends a message to the client using arguments(I am not good with explaining myself) but basically my issue is this

Server Console:

```
Command: >senddata 127.0.0.1 32
```

Clients Response:

```
Command Accepted!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Desktop\client\client.py", line 18, in <module>
    ip = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am sending 32 bytes of data(I think) to 127.0.0.1 and it wont work

This is my clients code:

```
import socket
import sys

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8888

socket.connect((host, port))

while True:
    msg = socket.recv(1024)

    if ">senddata".lower() in msg:
        print("Command Accepted!")
        ip = sys.argv[1]
        datasize = sys.argv[2]

        data = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        port = 80
        data.sendto(datasize, (ip, port))
        print("Sent")
```

I seriously cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: sys.argv is a list of command arguments that was used when starting your application.  It looks like what you want to do is get the ip and datasize from the message sent over your socket?  sys.argv isn't going to help you with that.

Comment: mateo what should i do then

Comment: Are you expecting the ip and data size to be in msg?  If yes then you could split the msg up. with https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading from msg, not sys.argv.

```
    if ">senddata".lower() in msg:
        print("Command Accepted!")
        ip = msg.split(" ")[1]
        datasize = msg.split(" ")[2]
```

Comment: what im trying to do is make my server tell the client to do something like that though I am not trying to do it directly to the client

Comment: It is about the error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: btw im not using linux im using windows and >senddata is the command I type in the server for the client to recieve

Comment: Ah ok, now I get you. You didn't expain well hehe. I will edit my post

Comment: Try it, you are reading from msg, not sys.argv hehe. I though you were running from the command line hehe

Comment: I edited the code to print out what was inputed and all it said was this Command Accepted!
>udp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Desktop\client\client.py", line 36, in <module>
    data.sendto(psize, (ip, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
ive renamed a few of the things but that doesnt matter cause i made them work with the rename

Comment: That's mean that the ip address has not the correct format. Did you fix? (Anyway, It is another problem, not the main question hehe)

Comment: one more question going off topic how would i use that code but for integer arguments?

Comment: The arguments can not be integers, but you can convert from string to integer. eg. int(sys.argv[2])

Comment: yeeah i figured it out a few mins ago